# Multithreading. How to ping several IPs simultaneously properly?

Tags: python, multithreading

I would like to make console program which ping remote IPs. I use multithreading to ping several IP simulteneously. When all IPs is reachable, all look great, but when one IP is not reachable, other threads have to wait long until the bad ping is finished (I chose one unpingable IP in purpose), due to join method, which waits until all threads is ended. When I just removed join method my PC crushed.

I did the following to overcome the issue (created infinite ping function, so no thead can be ended due to infinite method inside) and kept joinmethod in code, it works right, but is there any better choice? I guess the solution can have some drawbacks in resourse consuming or any other.

My working code, which I have doubts with:

The method below do one ping to `b` (IP) within t100 time interval

```
def do_ping(b,t100):
    a=os.system(f"ping -n 1 {b}")
    h=good_time(time.localtime(),1)
    with open(f"noob_{h}_{b}.txt",mode="a") as f:
        t=good_time(time.localtime(),0)
        if(a==int(0)):
             f.write(f"The remote destination {b} is reachable, everyting is enter code hereOKAY. {t} \n")
        elif(a==int(1)):
            f.write(f"Ping {b} failed! {t} \n") 
            time.sleep(int(t100))
```

infinite ping of one IP adress:

```
def ping1(b,t100):
     while(True):   
          IP_Op.do_ping(b,t100)
```

main program:

```
while(True):
    treadsN=[]
    for i in b:
```

`b` is a list of IPs (the whole program also writes results in files and in future will send emails if ping fail for long period

```
treadsN.append(threading.Thread(target=IP_Op.ping1, args=(i,3)))
     for i in treadsN:
          i.start()

      for i in treadsN:
           i.join()
```

Comment: You never exist the threads so you never actually join back to the main thread.  what is the problem with waiting for the one bad one?  seems like that is ok.  your worst case is probably waiting the wait of one bad endpoint (since your pinging in parallel the timeouts for multiple address that don't respond will be about the same time.

Comment: Hello, the code works as you say, I get right results, but in the future I would like to add event like keystroke, which do not stop pinging, but  returns to the initial setup menu (list of questions in the beggining of script) to add or remove some ips.   I was advised to do the following, please see next message.

Comment: Advise which was givven: Generically, your design should use a dispatcher and a queue.
The dispatcher fills the queue with tasks. Each thread is waiting for something in the queue. When a thread gets something, it executes the task and returns the value to the dispatcher. This way, everything is independent of each other. It makes no difference how fast or slow an individual thread is. It runs at its own speed, independent of any other thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need threads to execute multiple processes - Just use `subprocess.Popen` - it doesn't block like `os.system`, so you can just run it multiple times and they will all run in parallel.

If `b` is a list that contains all your ips:

```
import subprocess

while True:
    result = []
    for ip in b:
        p = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-n', '1', ip]) # runs ping in background
        result.append(p) # store the Popen object for later result retrieval
```

That will run multiple `ping` processes in the background! Now you just need to parse the results:

```
    try_again = []
    for ip, p in zip(b, result):
        if p.wait() == 0:
            print(ip, 'is ok!')
        else:
            print(ip, 'failed!')
            try_again.append(ip)
```

You can then repeat the ones that failed if you want:

```
    if not try_again:
        break
    time.sleep(100)
    b = try_again
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll test it soon. I was given the following advise, but I do not understand what code shold be, could you advise? The advise: your design should use a dispatcher and a queue.
The dispatcher fills the queue with tasks. Each thread is waiting for something in the queue. When a thread gets something, it executes the task and returns the value to the dispatcher. This way, everything is independent of each other. It makes no difference how fast or slow an individual thread is. It runs at its own speed, independent of any other thread.

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev my advice is still to not use threads! Your threads will do nothing, they will mostly be idle and waiting for the output of the ping command anyway so why waste so many resources just to keep waiting in multiple fronts?

Comment: thanks a lot, I am inexperience in programming, so ask weird questions. I thought that multithreading is the only option. I will read about subrocess and try to implement it.